# iCloud app cannot be installed on Windows 10

Tags: icloud, windows, install

Recently I reinstalled my OS on my Laptop and tried to install iCloud for Windows 10 and unfortunately I am unable to do so because at the end of it I got this error:

> There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

I have tried uninstalling all the Apple apps through the Control Panel (successfully) and then start with installing the iCloud for Windows again. Also I've tried uninstalling all of them (successfully) with `MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall` and still nothing. Tried installing iCloud via `Apple Software Update` and the installation goes through but I can't open/start the program.

Went through everything as stated [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205788) and still I can't fix the issue.

Installing iTunes is okay I've tried both ways, via `Microsoft Store` and standalone installer.

Comment: That page you linked to states "Errors like this are related to components of Windows that iTunes from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10 doesn't use."  It give a [different set of tasks to follow (from Windows 7)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204275).  Did you follow those steps on the other page?

Comment: @fsb Should I uninstall all of those programs in that order, restart and try to install the iCloud? Also I can see this artical is about iTunes not about iCloud.

Comment: I don't know.  The link you provided in your question indicates you should follow a different set of instructions.  I would recommend you follow those instructions, even if they say to remove software.  I've never had this problem, I'm just indicating the steps that Apple says to take.

Comment: This didn't resolve my issue. I still got the same error even after following those exact steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say that my problem was solved with reinstalling the Windows 10. It looks there was a corruption in the Windows Installer service that could only have been fixed with reinstall.

1) First I tried if I can install the iCloud with the default Administrator account:

> Open Start
>
> Type: cmd
>
> *Click Run as administrator
>
> At the command prompt type: net user administrator /active:yes
>
> Close command prompt, restart, then try signing into the Administrator account.
>
> Try running the file again.

2) Next thing that I tried was:

> Press Windows key + R
>
> Type: regedit
>
> Hit Enter

Navigate to the registry path: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

Temporarily modify these 3 registry keys:

> CurrentBuild set value to 17134 (instead of 17763)
>
> CurrentBuildNumber set value to 17134 (instead of 17763)
>
> ReleaseId set value to 1803 (instead of 1809)

**Install iCloud: *iCloudSetup.exe*. When finished, do not restart yet. Restore initial values of the 3 keys (step 3). Restart PC and complete setup of iCloud**

For Windows 10 in 32-bit version, the path is: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion`

> - Also you should check if you have Windows 10 in `S` mode installed.

Last thing I have tried before reinstalling the OS was uninstalling all Apple Software this includes iTunes, Apple Support software etc. Please uninstall them in the following order (as stated in this [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204275))

> 1) iTunes
>
> 2) Apple Software Update
>
> 3) Apple Mobile Device Support
>
> 4) Bonjour
>
> 5) Apple Application Support 32-bit
>
> 6) Apple Application Support 64-bit

Use [Revouninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/) ([HOW TO?](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-completely-uninstall-software/)) to thoroughly remove all Apple Software. Also make sure you uninstall the Apple Software Updater too. Try installing iCloud and iTunes again.

And if you fail after all of this try reinstalling your Windows 10 because that solved my issue with iCloud.

Hopefully this helped for those who have the same issue that I had.

**NOTE: This steps were taken with previously consultation with an Independent Advisor on the Microsoft Community Forum.**

Answer (score 0):

On the linked article:

> If you downloaded iTunes from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10 or aren't seeing this error message, don't use the steps in this article. Instead, learn how to remove and reinstall iTunes and related software components for Windows 7 and later. Errors like this are related to components of Windows that iTunes from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10 doesn't use.

Follow the steps found [here.](https://support.apple.com/HT204275) Make sure you uninstall everything in the right order.

> In some rare instances, you might need to remove iTunes and related software components before you reinstall iTunes or install iTunes from the Microsoft Store. If you're directed to reinstall iTunes by AppleCare, an article, or an alert dialog, you can do so by following the steps below.

Afterwards, install the software from the Microsoft Software.

Comment: I hope with `Microsoft Software` u are referring to `Microsoft Store`. If so, iCloud is a standalone installer. And my problem is about installing the iCloud not iTunes. For iTunes I can do both ways - with standalone installer and downloading it from MS Store.